# Build serverless data pipeline with AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth, aws-lambda, google-analytics-api, serverless

Unfortunately, I am struggling with the part of calling the google analytics API and the authorization via oauth. Does someone have a clear answer how to approach this topic. I'd like to run this sample code from google: 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/installed-py

Answer (score 0):

1. [Include google application default credentials json on project root
   folder](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials)
2. Install google-api-python-client dependencies
3. Zip folder content
4. Upload to AWS Lambda, set the python filename as lambda handler
5. Set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS as environment variable key and
   your credentials json file name as value on AWS Lambda management

This works for all my lambda functions that use google api and
    require credentials

Comment: Finally I've figured out how to build the google api service object. It is important that you set cache to false like this discover.build(api, version, http=http, cache_discovery=False)

Comment: Someone could then simply access your credentials json file online though right?