# Authorize google service account using AWS Lambda/API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless, service-accounts

My express server has a credentials.json containing credentials for a google service account. These credentials are used to get a jwt from google, and that jwt is used by my server to update google sheets owned by the service account.

```js
var jwt_client = null;

// load credentials form a local file
fs.readFile('./private/credentials.json', (err, content) => {
    if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
    // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Sheets API.
    authorize(JSON.parse(content));
});

// get JWT
function authorize(credentials) {
    const {client_email, private_key} = credentials;
    jwt_client = new google.auth.JWT(client_email, null, private_key, SCOPES); 
}

var sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth: jwt_client });

// at this point i can call google api and make authorized requests
```

The issue is that I'm trying to move from node/express to npm serverless/aws. I'm using the same code but getting 403 - forbidden.

```
 errors:
   [ { message: 'The request is missing a valid API key.',
       domain: 'global',
       reason: 'forbidden' } ] }
```

Research has pointed me to many things including: [AWS Cognito](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-enable-cognito-user-pool.html), [storing credentials in environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47794952/build-serverless-data-pipeline-with-aws-lambda), [custom authorizers in API gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-custom-authorizers-in-amazon-api-gateway/). All of these seem viable to me but I am new to AWS so any advice on which direction to take would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

it is late, but may help someone else. Here is my working code.

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const KEY = require('./keys');
const _ = require('lodash');

const sheets = google.sheets('v4');

const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    KEY.client_email,
    null,
    KEY.private_key,
    [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
    ],
    null
);

async function getGoogleSheetData() {
    await jwtClient.authorize();
    const request = {
            // The ID of the spreadsheet to retrieve data from.
            spreadsheetId: 'put your id here',  
    
            // The A1 notation of the values to retrieve.
            range: 'put your range here',  // TODO: Update placeholder value.
            auth: jwtClient,
        };
   return await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(request)
}
```

And then call it in the lambda handler. There is one thing I don't like is storing key.json as file in the project root. Will try to find some better place to save.